# PHP session gc_maxlifetime use master value instead of local

Tags: php, session, shared-hosting

I'm trying to set this value to 12h on a shared hosting and totally failing.
**ini_get** (after session_start()) return the correct seconds, also in the **php_info()** it show the correct local value but the session keep expiring at the *master value*.

I've tried to use the **local php.ini** and also **.htaccess**, and **ini_set** (before session_start()) too... all methods failed... Tried to set **gc_probability** & **gc_divisors** too.

I tried to open a ticket with the hosting and they told me to use php, but ini_set didn't worked.
I'm clueless now, what could I try?

It's a problem of the hosting?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you are on shared hosting. Some settings are locked there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a brainstorming with other programmer and the worst hosting assistance ever I end up solving the problem by just changing the folder for sessions storage. This solution will also require to manage the cancellation of obsolete sessions with a cronjob.